# Artifactory - How to back up drives larger than 1TB?

Tags: artifactory, backups

Artifactory has a built in backup solution. [The documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Backups) for artifactory warns that the built in backup is not optimized for drives larger than 1TB, and you should contact support for the recommended configuration.

[image]

How do you optimize artifactory backups for more than 1TB.

Currently I'm doing the standard daily and weekly backups. I'm finding that the weekly backups are taking 6+ hours.

Answer (score 1):

JFrog recommends not using the built in backup and instead doing database snapshots at the same time that you backup the entire $ARTIFACTORY_HOME location on the hard drive using a classic backup tool (rsync,cp, drbd)

A blog post covering how to do this can be found here: 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Backups